# Classicthesis/KOMA place page number above the footer line

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, classicthesis

I'm using the article class from the classicthesis package. I need a customized header and footer. I'm very close to the desired output but don't know how to add the page number above the footer line. Below is an image that shows the desired output. In addition, how can I increase the header size? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude,headinclude]{article} 

 \usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

  \usepackage{graphicx}

   \areaset[current]{350pt}{761pt}

    \begin{document}

     \clearscrheadfoot

      \ihead{Header text}
       \chead{}
        \ohead{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{Logo.png}}

         \lofoot{\footnotesize website}
         \cfoot{\footnotesize\textbf{Footer Text}}
         \rofoot{\footnotesize phone}

          \setheadsepline{0.5pt}
           \setfootsepline{0.5pt}

            some dummy text

           \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Using `classicthesis` with a standard class instead of a `KOMA-Script` class, deactivates several features of `classicthesis`. If this is not a problem, it could even be good, because it avoids some not recommended combinations of KOMA-Script class with packages like `titlesec`.

There are several suggestions to add extra elements to the page style. Because `classicthesis` uses package `scrlayer-scrpage` the most powerful would be to add an extra layer either for the text below the horizontal line or for the page number above the line. Here an example for the last one:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude,headinclude]{article} 

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\areaset[current]{350pt}{761pt}

\clearpairofpagestyles% deprecated \clearscrheadfoot replaced

\ihead{Header text}% with single sided, this is the same like \lofoot
\chead{}
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{example-image}}}% image replaced
                                % to make the example working; \smash added to
                                % ignore the height of the image and therefore
                                % avoid a warning about the height of the head

\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize}% setting the basic font size of the page footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize}% setting the font size of the page number
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt,footsepline=.5pt}% deprecated \setheadsepline
                                % and \setfootsepline replaced

\ifoot{website}
\cfoot{\textbf{Footer Text}}
\ofoot{phone}

\makeatletter
\DeclareLayer[%
  foreground,% layer only used in foreground
  foot,% basic position in the foot
  hoffset=\sls@leftmargin{foot},% left position changed according to the original layers of scrlayer-scrpage
  addvoffset=-\baselineskip,% move it upwards
  contents={%
    \raggedleft\normalfont
    \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{\usekomafont{pagefoot}{\pagemark}}\par% the \par is needed to make \raggedleft work
  }%
]{pagenumber}
\makeatother
  
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber}% add the new layer to pagestyle scrheadings
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{pagenumber}% and also to the plain page style plain.scrheadings

\begin{document}

some dummy text

\end{document}
```

But there is a more general and easier suggestion: Using `\raisebox` to move the number above the line and to give it a zero height and depth:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude,headinclude]{article} 

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\areaset[current]{350pt}{761pt}

\clearpairofpagestyles% deprecated \clearscrheadfoot replaced

\ihead{Header text}% with single sided, this is the same like \lofoot
\chead{}
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{example-image}}}% image replaced
                                % to make the example working; \smash added to
                                % ignore the height of the image and therefore
                                % avoid a warning about the height of the head

\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize}% setting the basic font size of the page footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize}% setting the font size of the page number
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt,footsepline=.5pt}% deprecated \setheadsepline
                                % and \setfootsepline replaced

\ifoot{website}
\cfoot{\textbf{Footer Text}}
\ofoot{phone%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{1.2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\pagemark}}% added
                                % the page number right aligned without width
                                % and moved upwards without height an depth.
}

\begin{document}

some dummy text

\end{document}
```

Both examples result in:

[image: hole page with page number atop the foot rule]

Please note also my comments about deprecated code. For more information about the replacements see the KOMA-Script manual.

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @nanda Thank you works here by voting (clicking on the thumbs up) and, if applicable by accepting the answer (click on the hook).

Comment: Any idea on how to increase the head height? I've tried different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @nanda This would be another question and you should ask it separately (if it is not already asked). However `classicthesis` internally uses [package `typearea`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/typearea). With this options `headinclude`, `headlines`, `headheight` are described in the KOMA-Script manuals. An alternative would be to use [package `geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry). But note, IMHO `classicthesis` is not very flexible. So if you want several changes to it, it could be easier to start newly without it.